# Vue.js | Nuxt.js| Как через JavaScript вставить компонент или роут-ссылку?

Tags: javascript, html, css, vue.js, nuxt.js

Имеется элемент, при наведении на него в другом элементе нужно вывести NuxtLink на определенную страницу или компонент, например Subsection. Как это реализовать?

Заранее спасибо!

Пытался делать так, но в DOM просто вставляет не рабочая nuxt-link

```
document.querySelector('.shops-bar-subsections').classList.remove('dn');
  let subsections = document.querySelector('.shops-bar-subsections');
  subsections.innerHTML = '';
  for(let subsection of this.section.subsections)
  {
    subsections.innerHTML =  `<NuxtLink to='/remind' class="hint">Забыли пароль?</NuxtLink>`;
  }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Добавь в data переменную. [В случае vuetify](https://vuetifyjs.com/en/components/badges/#show-on-hover) оберни нужный элемент в `<v-hover v-model="hover">`. NuxtLink клади сразу в нужное место и включай-выключай через v-if `<NuxtLink to='/remind' class="hint" v-if=hover>Забыли пароль?</NuxtLink>`.